# Where to put code if I want each row to display a different video file?

Tags: ios, swift, video, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Currently I have my code setup to where in each table view cell there is a button that displays a video after is pressed. Each table view cell row contains the button (there are x amount of cells) however no matter which row the button is tapped in it always leads to the same video. Is there a way to make to where, depending on the row the button is in, it displays a video? My code only has one video file in it currently but how could I make it to where depending on the cell the button is tapped in, it shows a specific video? For example, if the button is tapped in row one I want it to show a certain video, and the same for two, and three, and so on. Right now they all display the same video.

Here is my code for the table view cell:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class VideoPlayerView: UIView {

    let pauseButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Triangle 2"), for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.tintColor = UIColor.white
        button.isHidden = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePause), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()

    var isPlaying = false

    func handlePause() {
        if isPlaying {
            player?.pause()
            pauseButton.alpha = 1.0 }

        else { player?.play()
            pauseButton.alpha = 0.01
        }

        isPlaying = !isPlaying
    }

    //container view that holds sublayers for the video control objects
    let controlsContainerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 1.0)
        return view
    }()

    ...
}

 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    //setupPlayerView()

    //configures container view (video's background)
    controlsContainerView.frame = frame
    addSubview(controlsContainerView)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.black


    //following adds pause/play button to video
    controlsContainerView.addSubview(pauseButton)
    pauseButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    pauseButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true


}

var player: AVPlayer?

//function that sets up video playback
private func setupPlayerView() {



    //variable that contains video url
    let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BlackHeartBB/dunk.mov")

        player = AVPlayer(url: fileUrl)

    //video only renders if you specify 'playerLayer'
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        self.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 1)
        playerLayer.frame = frame


        player?.play()


        //attached obeserver of 'player' to tell when 'player' is ready
        player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)

}
//method called every time you add obserever to an object
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    //strring that lets AVPlayer know its ready
    if keyPath == "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges" {

        //configures container view while video is playing
        controlsContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        pauseButton.alpha = 0.05
        isPlaying = true

    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


}

class DrillsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var videoURL:[URL] = [URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BlackHeartBB/dunk.mov"), URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BlackHeartBB/mk.MOV")]
var video = URL(fileURLWithPath: String())


@IBOutlet weak var logoImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var drillTitle: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func watchButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print(123)


        //controls video background view
        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            let view = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


           view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.height)

            let videoPlayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.width * 9 / 16)
            let videoPlayerView = VideoPlayerView(frame: videoPlayerFrame)
            view.addSubview(videoPlayerView)


            keyWindow.addSubview(view)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                    view.frame = keyWindow.frame

            }, completion: { (completedAnimation) in
                //possible features implemented later
                UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true


            })



    }

}
```

}